# Robotframework become blank page on browser after long time waiting reply from server

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a test case that's need to upload file excel that's need to wait until sucess and it's took around 10-15mn to wait when click submit .
But i got erorr while i'm waiting around 6-7 minutes the screen browser is become blank lik my screenshot below . 
[image]

Here is a code :

```
TC_WEB_00005-AbnormalCase-Upload-Payroll-Not-Enought
        [Documentation]  Upload payroll for fail test
        Set Selenium Speed      0.3s
        Load Configuration Data     ${config_path}
        LoadCom_ID
        Login TMC Web   ${browser}      ${url}      ${user}     ${pwd}
        click element       //*[@id="menu_file"]/div/div/ul/li[15]/a
        click element       //*[@id="menu_file"]/div/div/ul/li[15]/ul/li[12]/a
        choose file         id=excel         ${CURDIR}/tmp_payroll_upoad.xlsx
        choose file         id=doc         ${CURDIR}/res/mypdf.pdf
        ${time}=    get time
        ${time}=   Get Substring    ${time}    -8   -6
        log to console  ${time}
        input text      id=effective-hours      ${time}
        input text       id=remark           Test fromQA
        click element      //div[@class='col-md-2']/input[@class='btn']
        element should be visible       //div[@class='alert alert-danger']          1800s

        [Teardown]    close browser
```

and the final i get erorr message below :

> TimeoutException: Message: timeout   (Session info:
>   chrome=66.0.3359.181)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

***PS: For manual test is fine, but it's become blank like this while in automated test only .***

Comment: Is it expected behaviour for the upload to last 6-7 minutes when doing the test manually? This part was not clear to me in your question.

Comment: I mean that's 6-7 minutes my browser become blank (Automated test) . i tihnk it's becuase of chromeDriver.  I try to update driver also but still same.

Comment: So when you do the test manually then you do not have this 6-7 min wait. Correct?

Comment: @SidaraKEO, was the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Check errors in logs; console errors.

It might be possible that the developer might have merged the code and had some storage error

Don't close the browser while running automation, inspect the page network,session storage with developer